# How to display all posts assigned the same category?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-theming

I have a product category called Cable, and I want to grab all posts assigned to this category and output the title of said posts. This category is from the custom taxonomy 'Category' that woo-commerce adds, I'm not sure if that makes things harder? but I haven't found a solution yet.

Could anyone assist with this?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this code:

And modify as per your requirements:

```
add_shortcode( 'specific_category_posts', 'kb_get_posts' );
function kb_get_posts() {

    $query = new WP_Query(
    array(
        'post_type'      => 'product',
        'post_status'    => 'publish',
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'tax_query'      => array(
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
                'field'    => 'term_id',
                'terms'    => array( '18' ), //Your custom category id
            ),
        ),
    )
);

if ( $query->have_posts() ) {
    while ( $query->have_posts() ) {
        $query->the_post();
        echo '<h2>' . get_the_title() . '</h2>';
    }
}
wp_reset_postdata();
}
```

Comment: For 'product_cat' would there be a way to use the id instead? I'd like to use the id of the current page instead of typing the name of it if possible

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`WP_Query()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/)  with tax_query().

**EDIT:**

Try out this code to get products on category page.

```
add_shortcode('product_list', 'zillion_show_products_title_by_cat', 10);
function zillion_show_products_title_by_cat()
{
    if(!is_product_category()){
        return;
    }
    $term = get_queried_object();
    
    ob_start();
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'product',
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'tax_query' => array(
             'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
             'field'    => 'term_id',
             'terms'     =>  $term->term_id, // 21 is category id When you have more term_id's seperate them by comma.
             'operator'  => 'IN'
        )
    );
    $the_query = new WP_Query($args);

    // The Loop
    if ($the_query->have_posts()) {
        while ($the_query->have_posts()) {
            $the_query->the_post();
            echo '<h3>' . get_the_title() . '</h3>';
        }
    } else {
        // no posts found
    }
    /* Restore original Post Data */
    wp_reset_postdata();

    $contents = ob_get_clean();
    return $contents;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this code to show all posts assigned to the category **cable**

```
<?php
    global $post;
    $args = array( 'numberposts' => 10, 'category_name' => 'cable' );
    $posts = get_posts( $args );
    foreach( $posts as $post ): setup_postdata($post); 
?>

<div> 
    <?php 
    the_title(); 
    the_excerpt(); ?>
</div>

<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: Instead of 'category_name', is there a way to use the current pages cat id instead? I'd like to use the id of the current page instead of typing the name of it if possible

Answer (score 1):

I have created with list

```
add_shortcode( 'pi_cable_posts', 'pi_posts' );
function pi_posts() {
$pi_query = new WP_Query(
array(
    'post_type'      => 'product',
    'post_status'    => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page' => -1, //--1 for unlimited and number to limit
    'tax_query'      => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
            'field'    => 'term_id',
            'terms'    => array( 'YOUR ID HERE' ), //ADD YOUR ID HERE
        ),
    ),
));

if ( $pi_query ->have_posts() ) {
echo '<ul>';
while ( $pi_query ->have_posts() ) {
    $pi_query ->the_post();
    echo '<li><h2><a href="'.get_the_permalink().'">' . get_the_title() . '</h2></li>';
}
echo '</ul>';
}
wp_reset_postdata();}
```